# Long running code on a background thread?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have the following method in one of my business managers:

```
    public ImportItemsResult Import(String fullPath)
    {
        OleDbDataManager oleDbDataManager = new OleDbDataManager();
        List<ItemInfo> importedData = oleDbDataManager.GetData<ItemInfo>(fullPath, ItemInfoMapper).ToList();
        ImportItemsResult result = ValidateImportedData(importedData);
        if (result.Status == OperationStatus.Success)
        {
            //do something with importedData in the background and return 
            //the result to the user right away
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The code allows the user to upload a .csv file which then gets parsed and validated. After it's validated, if all the data was okey the data is processed and saved to the database, otherwise the file is rejected and a detailed error message is show to the user on the UI.

**Questions:**

- Is it safe to assume that once the validation results in a success status, the processing should - theoretically - go fine due to the fact that all data is valid?
- Is it possible to run the processing code on a background thread and return from that method right away? Can I do that inside the if-statement in the code above or do I need to re-structure the whole thing?

The reason why I thought about this in the first place is because I need to expose this functionality via a WCF web-service, and I have no idea how long it's going to process the data which might cause the web-service to time-out in case it took too long. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is you WCF service IIS hosted or self hosted?

Comment: AFAIR in IIS you have no background thread.

Comment: Excuse me, is this C# or android ?? Edit your tags please !

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D it wasn't really me who added the tags, someone must have edited my question and added them. I never develop Android applications. Thanks for mentioning that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here:

- The only 'safe' thing to assume is that everything that can go wrong **will** go wrong. You should probably use transactions when writing to the database.
- While it's definitely possible to post the operation to the thread pool (even on IIS), I don't see what it would achieve. You still need to send a response to the client. A few more questions you need to ask:

  - How long is 'long'? Is it feasible for the client to wait? You can increase the service's send timeout to a reasonable number.
  - If you do need a truly asynchronous operation, you can use other mechanisms, such as duplex channels or some sort of pub/sub. Then the call can return immediately and the client can wait for a reply using these mechanisms. But this will make the design much more complex.
- You also have the option to stream the data in and process it as it comes along, instead of one big chunk. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx). It could save some time, because you'd be processing chunks as soon as possible (this wouldn't work if you need to validate the data set as a whole.)

Answer (score 0):

After validation there are still things that could go wrong - your WCF service could crash or the machine it is on loses power - you lose all data.

You need to persist the CSV data to a non-volatile medium **before** returning the result. Also I would put the long running code into a separate windows service (assuming your WCF service is IIS hosted otherwise you could combine the two), that just does the processing. You could use a database that both the WCF web service and that windows service use to store and retrieve the CSV data from.

Comment: Yes I'm definitely persisting the CSV file to disk before sending back the result. The WCF service is hosted in IIS. So basically, your saying it's safe to send the result after validation as long as I could recover the data (logs, email notifications...etc) in case something unexpected happened?

Comment: Assuming the result cannot change after validation and you have persisted the data so you can guarantee that it is going to be processed - what is the *unexpected* thing that could happen? If your validation does not guarantee that your data can be processed maybe you should focus there.

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust parameters or expect an "all things will run fine", you should use try/catch statements and implement something to handle errors (log something somewhere, send detailled informations to clients service, ...).

To prevent timeout you should set your WCF service to support asynchronous operation.

Btw, does your OleDbDataManager is IDisposable ? if so you should include an using keyword to prevent memory leaks.